# How to extract line from the file on specific condition?

Tags: command-line

Suppose i have a file with 50K lines, consider (Account,Cusip) as primary key. I would like to keep the last line among lines with the same primary key.
those lines that, for the lines with same primary key, keep the last linehow can I achieve this?

```
Account  Cusip   Amount  
A        a       500
A        a       450
A        b       500
B        b       600
B        b       350
C        a       300
C        c       100
C        c       200
C        c       500
```

---

Expected result

```
Account  Cusip   Amount 
A        a       450
A        b       500
B        b       350
C        a       300
C        c       500
```

Comment: What operating system are you using and what command line do you have available? Bash, cmd, powershell or anything else?

Comment: @Walmart: he want the last line of any primary key, so the value of `Amount` column is not considered.

Answer (score 1):

Use following python script to do as you expected. The file `1.txt` contains your input data:

```
key1=''
key2=''
amount=''
with open('1.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
        [nkey1,nkey2,namount]=line.split()
        if nkey1==key1 and nkey2==key2:
                amount=namount
        else:
                print '%s\t%s\t%s' % (key1,key2,amount)
                key1=nkey1
                key2=nkey2
                amount=namount
   print '%s\t%s\t%s' % (key1,key2,amount)
```